# JavaScript: is it possible for closures to access variables in the enclosing scope by value rather than by reference like in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, closures, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

The following JavaScript code demonstrates how
JavaScript (closure) functions access the variables
in their enclosing environment by reference rather
than by value.

```
var sum; // global variable

function outer() {
  var hundred_more = 100;
  sum = function (a, b) {
    return a + b + (++hundred_more);
  };
  sum2 = function (a, b) {
    return a + b + (++hundred_more);
  };
  alert(hundred_more);
}
outer(); // define sum at the global scope and print 100
alert(sum(5, 10)); // 116
alert(sum(5, 10)); // 117
alert(sum2(5, 10)); // 118
alert(sum2(5, 10)); // 119
outer(); // redefine sum at the global scope and print 100
alert(sum(5, 10)); // 116
alert(sum(5, 10)); // 117
alert(sum2(5, 10)); // 118
alert(sum2(5, 10)); // 119
```

The same code in PHP looks as follows:

```
<?php

$sum = null; // global variable
$sum2 = null; // global variable

function outer() {
  global $sum;
  global $sum2;
  $hundred_more = 100;
  $sum = function ($a, $b) use (&$hundred_more) {
    return $a + $b + (++$hundred_more);
  };
  $sum2 = function ($a, $b) use (&$hundred_more) {
    return $a + $b + (++$hundred_more);
  };
  var_dump($hundred_more);
}
outer(); // define sum at the global scope and print 100
var_dump($sum(5, 10)); // 116
var_dump($sum(5, 10)); // 117
var_dump($sum2(5, 10)); // 118
var_dump($sum2(5, 10)); // 119
outer(); // redefine sum at the global scope and print 100
var_dump($sum(5, 10)); // 116
var_dump($sum(5, 10)); // 117
var_dump($sum2(5, 10)); // 118
var_dump($sum2(5, 10)); // 119
```

To pass the variable from the enclosing environment by value rather than by reference
in PHP you simply omit the ampersand (&) in front of the variables after the use keyword.
This causes the value to be copied into the function's closure scope at the time the
function is defined, so that all 'var_dumps' print the value 116. Is it possible to
somehow achieve this same construct in JavaScript (with variables passed to the
inner closure by value rather than by reference)?

Thanks.

Comment: The only parameters I see being passed are the numeric constants `5` and `10`. What specific part of the code are you asking about?

Comment: I don't mean the arguments to the function. I mean the variables from the enclosing scope (like those after the use keyword in PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could create another closure for it...

```js
function outer() {
    var hundred_more = 100;
    sum = (function(hundred_more){
        return function (a, b) {
          return a + b + (++hundred_more);
        };
    })(hundred_more);
    sum2 = (function(hundred_more){
        return function (a, b) {
          return a + b + (++hundred_more);
        };
    })(hundred_more);
    alert(hundred_more);
}
outer(); // define sum at the global scope and print 100
alert(sum(5, 10)); // 116
alert(sum(5, 10)); // 117
alert(sum2(5, 10)); // 116
alert(sum2(5, 10)); // 117
outer(); // redefine sum at the global scope and print 100
alert(sum(5, 10)); // 116
alert(sum(5, 10)); // 117
alert(sum2(5, 10)); // 116
alert(sum2(5, 10)); // 117
```

It's not actually passing by reference; they're just referencing the same variable. By creating a new closure, we pass the old one by reference, and get decoupled variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand your answer, it makes use of the fact that when a parameter is passed to a function in JavaScript it is passed by value (as in the follwing snippet).

Comment: function hello(a) { a='hello'; alert(a); }
var a = 'world';
hello(a); / * displays hello * /
alert(a); / * displays world * /

Comment: This is unlike the assignment statement in JavaScript which just creates a reference to the variable being assigned rather than copying it. Thanks.